# How can I create an NFT that people can only mint by my website?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How can I create an NFT that people can only mint by my website? Instead of people can mint directly from the contract or other ways.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust yourself, you can create a backend server. With this server, you can sign an object like:

```
{
   requestID: 123,
}
```

Send this signature and object to your contract and verify, is it sent from your backend. If it is sent from your backend server, check other parameters. Don't forget to mark these signatures as true when a transaction is successful.

Comment: thankyou！ it's really helpful. do you have recommmend  tutorial about this?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26) will be helpful

Comment: another question,  Do you know any server website I can use to create the backend server?  I am a noob about server - -  (maybe something like moralis?)

Comment: Maybe you can create an ubuntu linux machine from a cloud and write the API in this machine.